# How to animate position absolute from right to left and then left to right in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, pug

I am trying to make a simple game in which a boat goes from one shore to another shore when `GO` button is clicked. I tried to use jQuery `animate` but it didn't worked as expected.

***Pug***

```
body
  button.go GO
  .main 
    .left 
      .seaShore
    .travel 
      .boat
      .river 
    .right 
      .seaShore
```

***Sass***

```
*
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    box-sizing: border-box

@mixin flex($justify,$align)
    display: flex
    justify-content: $justify
    align-items: $align

.go
    padding: 5px 10px
    position: fixed
    top: 20px
    right: 50%
    transform: translateX(50%)

.main
    height: 100vh
    @include flex(center,flex-end)

.seaShore
    background-color: green
    width: 25vw
    height: 300px

.travel
    position: relative
    .boat
      position: absolute
      top: -15px
      right: 0
      width: 200px
      height: 40px
      border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%
      background-color: brown

    .river
        width: 50vw
        height: 290px
        background-color: #00bfff
```

***jQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let right = false;
  let offset = $('.boat').offset();
  $(".go").click(function () {
    !right
      ? $(".boat").animate(
          {
            left: "0",
            right: offset.left - 200
          },
          "veryfast"
        )
      : $(".boat").animate(
          {
            left: offset.left - 100,
            right: 0
          },
          "veryfast"
        );

    right = !right;
  });
});
```

The problem is when the boat is coming back to the starting position then it is going a bit further than the original position.

Can any one please help me?

[CODE PEN LINK](https://codepen.io/amankumar6/pen/KKNxGML?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `$('.boat').offset()` use `document.querySelector('.boat').offsetLeft` it will fix your problem and it will also be dynamic.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let right = false,
        offset = document.querySelector('.boat').offsetLeft;
    $('.go').click(function () {
        !right
            ? $('.boat').animate({ left: '0', right: offset }, 'veryfast')
            : $('.boat').animate({ left: offset, right: 0 }, 'veryfast');
        right = !right;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a dynamic solution ? If not then you can just modify the value to subtract

e.g change

```
left: offset.left - 100,
```

to become

```
left: offset.left - 382,
```

And you can just play around with the number -382 to ensure it fits nicely

Comment: obviously i need a dynamic solution

Comment: Then you can start by avoiding the use of '- 200' and '- 100'. Start declaring the coordinate and width/height of your land and sea and what not. Once you have defined those, you will then be able to calculate the rest. e.g you will be able to figure out the width of the sea (which will be calculated into your delta to animate and move the boat)